# How can I implement Ajax Call in the bar chart js, my ajax response will come in json

Tags: ajax, bar-chart, chart.js

My Json response:

```
{ "iTotalRecords": 5,
  "productivity": [

{ "update_by": "chang", "count": 5},
{ "update_by": "cherry", "count": 5},
{ "update_by": "frankie", "count": 4},
{ "update_by": "jhon", "count": 3 },
{ "update_by": "peeter", "count": 4},
{ "update_by": "uccadmin", "count": 12},
{ "update_by": "victor", "count": 4}
]
}
```

I want to create a bar chart using productivity Array.